# Swift 3: Filtering IOS notifications

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

Im currently trying to filter the notifications that a user receives based on their location. I do have the code that tells us weather a user is within the desired location radius but I don't know how you would stop a notification. The methods I looked at ...

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
```

only gets run when the application is running in the foreground. So how would you receive an incoming notification and stop it before being displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you need correctly, you need to intercept the push notification before it presents the content to the user independently if the app is running in foreground, background or closed. For this purpose, you can use Notification service extension. There are many articles describing how to use it over the internet. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

When you are using the app and you get a notification, the method gets called, but doesn't show the notification because you are using the app (it's an iOS choice), when your app is in foreground you get the notification, the method doesn't get called until the user open the notification, so there is no way to stop a notification from showing.